# Edittext & textview value wont change even the value in the database is already change

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

edit text value wont change even the value in the database is already change, its show the previous content and I need to debug again the application to show the new data. I already use this but the value still not change until I debug it again.

i can insert in database using this code but when i display the value of it the old value is the one showing not the updated one. thats why the i say the edittext and textview value not changing.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_userdetails);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //if the user is not logged in
    //starting the login activity
    if (!SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
    User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUser();
    Circleimage = findViewById(R.id.Circleimage);
    bt_update = findViewById(R.id.bt_update);
    Btn_Editprofile = findViewById(R.id.Btn_Editprofile);
    textViewFullname = findViewById(R.id.textViewFullname);
    textViewId = findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    textViewLastname = findViewById(R.id.textViewLastname);
    textViewFirstname = findViewById(R.id.textViewFirstname);
    textViewMiname = findViewById(R.id.textViewMiname);
    textViewSuname = findViewById(R.id.textViewSuname);
    textViewUsername = findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
    textViewAddress = findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);
    textViewAddress1 = findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress1);
    textViewBirthday = findViewById(R.id.textViewBirthday);
    textViewBirthday1 = findViewById(R.id.textViewBirthday1);
    textViewEmail = findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
    textViewGender = findViewById(R.id.textViewGender);
    textViewHeight = findViewById(R.id.textViewHeight);
    textViewWeight = findViewById(R.id.textViewWeight);
    Btn_Editprofilepic= findViewById(R.id.Btn_Editprofilepic);
    spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    //getting the current user
    //setting the values to the textviews
    textViewFullname.setText(user.getFirstname() + " " + user.getLastname());
    textViewId.setText(String.valueOf(user.getId()));
    textViewLastname.setText(user.getLastname());
    textViewFirstname.setText(user.getFirstname());
    textViewMiname.setText(user.getMiddlename());
    textViewSuname.setText(user.getSuffix());
    textViewUsername.setText(user.getUsername());
    textViewAddress.setText(user.getAddress());
    textViewAddress1.setText(user.getAddress1());
    textViewBirthday.setText(user.getBirthday());
    textViewBirthday1.setText(user.getBirthday1());
    textViewEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
    textViewGender.setText(user.getGender());
    textViewHeight.setText(user.getHeight());
    textViewWeight.setText(user.getWeight());
    textViewdatashow = findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
 }
public void btn_update(View view) {
    final String Clastname = textViewLastname.getText().toString().trim();
    final String Cfirstname = textViewFirstname.getText().toString().trim();
    final String Cmiddlename = textViewMiname.getText().toString().trim();


    //first we will do the validations
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Clastname)) {
        textViewLastname.setError("Please enter Lastname");
        textViewLastname.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Cfirstname)) {
        textViewFirstname.setError("Please enter Firstname");
        textViewFirstname.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Cmiddlename)) {
        textViewMiname.setError("Please enter Middlename");
        textViewMiname.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Updating....");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.3.106/loginregister/update.php",
            response -> {

                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));

                progressDialog.dismiss();


            }, error -> {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }) {
        final String id = textViewId.getText().toString().trim();
        final String lastname = textViewLastname.getText().toString().trim();
        final String firstname = textViewFirstname.getText().toString().trim();
        final String middlename = textViewMiname.getText().toString().trim();
        final String suffix = textViewSuname.getText().toString().trim();
        final String username = textViewUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        final String address = textViewAddress.getText().toString().trim();
        final String address1 = textViewAddress1.getText().toString().trim();
        final String birthday = textViewBirthday.getText().toString().trim();
        final String birthday1 = textViewBirthday1.getText().toString().trim();
        final String email = textViewEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = textViewGender.getText().toString().trim();
        final String height = textViewHeight.getText().toString().trim();
        final String weight = textViewWeight.getText().toString().trim();
        final String vaccine = spinner1.getText().toString().trim();

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("id", id);
            params.put("lastname", lastname);
            params.put("firstname", firstname);
            params.put("middlename", middlename);
            params.put("suffix", suffix);
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("address", address);
            params.put("address1", address1);
            params.put("birthday", birthday);
            params.put("birthplace", birthday1);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("height", height);
            params.put("weight", weight);
            params.put("vaccine", vaccine);

            return params;

        }

    };

    bt_update.setEnabled(false);
    Btn_Editprofile.setEnabled(true);
    textViewAddress.setEnabled(false);
    textViewAddress1.setEnabled(false);
    textViewBirthday.setEnabled(false);
    textViewBirthday1.setEnabled(false);
    textViewGender.setEnabled(false);
    textViewHeight.setEnabled(false);
    textViewWeight.setEnabled(false);
    spinner1.setEnabled(false);
    Circleimage.setEnabled(false);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ProfileActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: Android studio is an IDE it has nothing to do with your problem , So pls edit your question wit proper title and tags .. remove all android studio tags and uses .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Share the code.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: i share my code sorry guys :)

Comment: You are declaring all of the UI elements (textViewLastname etc) as local variables in the OnCreate method, if you want to change the text in the update button, then you need to re-declare these variables or make them global (declare them out with either of the functions, making them accessible by both.